# Pico-ETH-CH9121 complete use case example

Tags: ethernet, pi-pico

I purchased Waveshare's Pico-ETH-CH9121 and followed the instructions at https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-ETH-CH9121. Unfortunately, I do not understand what to do to establish a TCP/IP connection, e.g. with "TCP Client mode".

Since the suggested SSCOM software appears to be for MS Windows only I wonder if anybody can provide a full use case example for Unix which implements the connection to a server's TCP/IP port and exchange of a few byte into each direction?

Comment: On Unix systems you could enable standard services like `echo` or `chargen` (see `/etc/services`) or use tools like `nc` (netcat) to create a TCP client or server or `telnet` as a TCP client.

Comment: @Bodo: Unfortunately, the Raspi Pico's design is to operate headless. No network (obviously), no display (if not attached via HAT), no keyboard. The ethernet HAT is not recognized by default (afaik) and requires a driver which is part of the problem.

Comment: I don't know what the SSCOM program does. The tools named in my previous comment might help with testing a TCP connection between the Pico and a UNIX system. My understanding is that you compile some software and send it to the Pico, and this may communicate with software on your UNIX system. Please make your problem clear *in the question*.